# Magento 2.3 - Product Import is still in In progress

Tags: magento2, import

I tried to import prices in **Magento 2.3 backend**. Checked data and saw no errors.

- I clicked *import button*,
  then it shows `Maximum error count has been reached` or **system error** is occurred!.

But in Import History it is still in progress.

How to cancel it? Can i delete data in import history table?

Comment: Did you find something in the logs?

Comment: No i cannot find anything there. After indexing price is updated. But still backend import history shows in progress

Comment: Did you find a way to stop imports showing "In Progress" in the Import History section?